# print values from list inside a list

Tags: list, python-2.7

i have this code in python:

```
sensor16=['1','-','\\','/','*','!']
sensor15=['4','G','H','I']
sensor14=['7','P','Q','R','S']
sensor13=['*']
sensor12=['2','A','B','C']
sensor11=['5','J','K','L']
sensor10=['8','T','U','V']
sensor09=['0',' ']
sensor08=['3','D','E','F']
sensor07=['6','M','N','O']
sensor06=['9','W','X','Y','Z']
sensor05=['#']
sensor04=['BACKSPACE']
sensor03=['DELETE ALL']
sensor02=['READ']
sensor01=['TRANSMITE']
sensor= [sensor01,sensor02,sensor03,sensor04,sensor05,sensor06,sensor07,sensor08,sensor09,sensor10,sensor11,sensor12,sensor13,sensor14,sensor15,sensor16]
press=[1,1,1,1,1,5,4,4,2,4,4,4,1,5,4]
num_press=0


for steps in range(15) :
    sensor[steps]
    num_press=press[steps]
    for i in range(num_press) :
        print(sensor[steps][num_press])
```

How can I access the value in each sensorXX list which corresponds to the value in press[] list?

For example `press[9]` is `4`, so I want to print `sensor10[4]` which is `V`

the reason that i have to go through press[] list is that i have already managed to get some timing functions so i know how much time passed since my last press, so i can either printout the next character inside the specific sensor number list ( e.g sensor01[] or sensor[12] ) and when i reach the maximum number of presses to reloop or i have to move my cursor one place right and start from begin.

i have already build and running in arduino but the code is in C. now i would like to move everything to my raspberry pi 2 and in python.

this was where the first idea came from, and i actually used most of that code to do so in arduino.
[youtube video for arduino use of my code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5FADQDrGrY)
[arduino code](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FWO/R38I/HQ9VUU35/FWOR38IHQ9VUU35.ino)

Comment: I sincerely don't understand the question. Do you have any sample desired output that you could add to perhaps make it a bit clearer?

Comment: how can print() the second value from sensor10[] list though sensor[] list ?

Comment: I edited your question to make the question clear and noticed that you have an off-by-one in your sensor list as well. You should just rename your sensors to be 0-15 instead of 1-16...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and got index out of range error. It looks like you just have off by one error. Try this: (Also removed your nested for loop it seems like a mistake)

```
for steps in range(15) :
    sensor[steps]
    num_press=press[steps]
    print (sensor[steps]) [num_press-1]
```

Output:

```
TRANSMITE
READ
DELETE ALL
BACKSPACE
#
Z
O
F

V
L
C
*
S
I
```

Comment: thank you very much for this response but this prints just the last one. I would like to print every one of them. if i go and say for steps in range(15) :
    print (sensor[steps]) it will print everything. but i need to be able and print individually every one on a deferent line.

Comment: this prints exactly the output that I pasted above, if you assigned it to a variable and then printed the variable after exiting the loop it would only show the last one.

Answer (score 0):

DOOOOONE ! AND THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR RESPONSE ! :D

```
sensor16=['1','-','\\','/','*','!']
sensor15=['4','G','H','I']
sensor14=['7','P','Q','R','S']
sensor13=['*']
sensor12=['2','A','B','C']
sensor11=['5','J','K','L']
sensor10=['8','T','U','V']
sensor09=['0',' ']
sensor08=['3','D','E','F']
sensor07=['6','M','N','O']
sensor06=['9','W','X','Y','Z']
sensor05=['#']
sensor04=['BACKSPACE']
sensor03=['DELETE ALL']
sensor02=['READ']
sensor01=['TRANSMITE']
sensor=[sensor01,sensor02,sensor03,sensor04,sensor05,sensor06,sensor07,sensor08,sensor09,sensor10,sensor11,sensor12,sensor13,sensor14,sensor15,sensor16]
press=[1,1,1,1,1,5,4,4,2,4,4,4,1,5,4]
num_press=0
steps=0

for steps in range (15):
    for i in range (press[steps]):
        print (sensor[steps][i])
```

and it goes to every value individually.

again ! thanks a lot ....